# Get data from file and split into an array

Tags: c#, regex

I have information formatted on a webpage which looks like the following:

```
Key=submission_id, Value=300348811884547965
Key=formID, Value=50514289063151
Key=ip, Value=xxxxx
Key=editimage, Value=Yes
Key=openimage5, Value=Yes
Key=copyimage, Value=Yes
```

How would I go about getting the value of each line, I was thinking of doing some sort of next() while getting all data after the 2nd equal sign of each line however I am unsure on how to do it in c#. I am sure there is a better solution then what I have in mind. Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: `(?<==)[^=]*$` or `(?<=Value=).*` or `=([^=]*)$` or `(?<=^(?:[^=]*=){2}).*` or `^(?:[^=]*=){2}(.*)`

Answer (score 1):

A regex works nicely for parsing data structured in this way.

```
        Regex splitter = new Regex(@"Key=([\w]+), Value=([\w]+)");

        string path = "TextFile1.txt";
        string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path);
        lines.ToList().ForEach((s) =>
        {
            Match match = splitter.Match(s);
            if (match.Success)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The Key is " + match.Groups[1] + " and the value is " + match.Groups[2]);
            }
        });
```